# Using articles before titles beginning with articles

Tags: grammaticality, articles, proper-nouns, writing-style

What are the rules for the use of articles before titles beginning with articles? Which of the following sentences is correct?

1. I went to **the The** New York Times office this morning.
2. I went to **The** New York Times office this morning.
3. I went to **the** New York Times office this morning.
4. I am reading **a The** New York Times article.
5. I am reading **a** New York Times article.

Are "the The" and "a The" grammatical? If not, which is the article that should be dropped? Or is it simply a question of style?

According to Google, there are [90.3 million instances](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the%20the%20new%20york%20times%22) of "the The New York Times" on the Internet including 340,000 hits within the nytimes.com domain. I'm sure that there are plenty of false positives, but there are genuine cases too such as in the following sentence:

> Writers from **the The** New York Times Dining section share Thanksgiving memories.

Comment: Can't let this one go without plugging one of my favorite bands, [the The](http://www.thethe.com/)...  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a1US5G9GMM8

Comment: For one thing, the choice of the example 'The New York Times' is not entirely suitable, it is more commonly referred without the article in its name, other than perhaps in very formal or legal writing. "I am reading a The New York Times article": I do not call it 'The New York Times' in this case, perhaps, not even 'New York'. "I am reading a  *Times* article" in actual practice.

Comment: @MT_Head: I'm with you on that one! I've always thought one of the reasons *The The* aren't as well-known as they should be is because they chose a name that isn't really compatible with computerised indexes (Google, music library searches, etc.). Lots of goodies on *Infected*, but *This Is the Day* on *Soul Mining* is my favourite (I always love a squeeze box!).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Matt Johnson lost me with "Naked Self" - I bought it the day it finally became available, but I don't think I've listened to it all the way through more than once - but what a glorious run it was while it lasted!  Also, ["Hanky Panky"](http://www.amazon.com/Hanky-Panky-The-The/dp/B000002AZD) turned me on to Hank Williams (Sr., NOT Jr.!), for which I remain grateful.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Let me clarify: I certainly knew OF Hank's music before that album, but I couldn't hear past the twang.  The The gave me a new perspective on the songs and I've been a fan ever since.

Comment: @MT_Head: I don't actually have *Hanky Panky*, but you're making me think I should. Per my somment, it'd probably be so awkward to search for a "bent" copy on P2P torrents that I might as well bite the bullet and go for a [secondhand $0.58 copy](http://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/B000002AZD/ref=tmm_acd_used_olp_sr?ie=UTF8&condition=used). I just get irritated when the shipping costs are so much higher than the item price itself!

Comment: *there are 90.3 million instances* Did you (in 2013) maybe instead mean "9.03 million"? Now in 2024, I get only "About 9,610,000 results".

Answer (score 1):

From grammatical considerations, some thumb rules for convenience could be applied. However, the question is largely one of style and less about grammar.

Firstly, when the title begins with an article, it is not always necessary to cite the article of the title. 'The New York Times' is referred to as the 'New York Times' in practice.

> I went to the <strike>The</strike> New York Times office this morning.

Secondly, when the title beginning article is the same as the article required before the title, it need not be repeated.

> I went to <strike>the</strike> The New York Times office this morning.

Thumb rule (2) provides an alternative to (1) so you may chose between capitalizing the article and not.

In the case of different articles as in

> I am reading a <strike>The</strike> New York Times article.

use thumb rule (1). Here the grammatical requirement of an article is more important.

Comment: What's a 'thumb rule'?

Comment: @Mitch + 1 uptick: Why the doubt? What exactly is meant by that?

Comment: I've just never heard the phrase 'thumb rule' before. It sounds like a funny kind of ruler whose measuring distance is in units of 'thumbs'. But Of course on rereading I think you are referring to 'rule of thumb'. I've never heard 'rule of thumb' transformed like you do to 'thumb rule'. A google search shows that it is rare, but does appear. It's just very unexpected.

Comment: @Mitch Hope there aren't many more things that "you've just never heard". You should use this excellent tool before offering comments: http://www.google.com (in the event you've just never heard of that one.)

Comment: Closer home: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10612203

Comment: If you use [Google nGrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rule+of+thumb%2C+thumb+rule&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=), you'll notice that 'rule of thumb' is a lot more common (in fact, 'thumb rule' flatlines against it). I don't doubt that people use 'thumb rule' naturally now (now that I've investigated it), but my initially surprise at the usage is borne out by the automated (but questionable) tool.

Comment: @Mitch 'thumb rule' is not incorrect, it's an accepted alternative to 'rule of thumb'. Both expressions are listed in dictionaries, authenticating their use. Lexicon: www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/thumb%20rule Usage: books.google.com/books?id=qW2QiD-8j88C p32; books.google.com/books?isbn=3642042880 pp200, 202. HTH

Comment: And where is that up voter to the comment? Anything they have to say?

Answer (score 0):

Anytime that the title of a publication has the definite article in it, then you can omit the use of a second one. For example, "Bob sent a letter to The New York Times office."